# 2 jquery ui datepicker near, datepicker not showing when I come from the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this simple html/js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="APP/HTML-COMMON/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="APP/HTML-COMMON/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js?2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="APP/HTML-COMMON/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="APP/HTML-COMMON/Css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=test]").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        , dayNames: ["Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"]
        , dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Gi", "Ve", "Sa"]
        , monthNames: ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"]
        , monthNamesShort: ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"]
        , changeYear: true
        , yearRange: "-100:+0"
        , showAnim: "fold"
    });

});     
//]]>
</script>

<input type="text" id="test1" />
<input type="text" id="test2" />
```

It works but, only one at time, examples:

1. clicking on 1st textbox correctly showing datepicker
2. refresh page, clicking on 2nd textbox correctly showing datepicker
3. refresh page, clicking on 1st textbox correctly showing datepicker, but not showing it tabbing on the 2nd textbox, to show the 2nd datepicker I have to focus other element in the page, and then put the focus on the 2nd textbox (the same if I click first 2nd textbox, the 1st).

Edit:
as  Bhushan Kawadkar asked this is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/falco77/vrrctfao/1/
After creating jsfiddle I understood problem is jquery-ui-1.10.4, for example using 1.7.2 (http://jsfiddle.net/falco77/vrrctfao) no problem...

But now I ask why... 1.10 is not more recent than 1.7?

Comment: can you please share the jsfiddle link with problem statement/

Comment: try fiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id^=test]").each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
         , dayNames: ["Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"]
         , dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Gi", "Ve", "Sa"]
         , monthNames: ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"]
         , monthNamesShort: ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"]
         , changeYear: true
         , yearRange: "-100:+0"
         , showAnim: "fold"
    });
});
```

Try: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/ezvuxa1g/)

Comment: as edited in the post I understood problem was jquery-ui version... I will use 1.7.2 as you suggested in your jsfiddle, but I ask myself why 1.10.4 was not good... maybe jquery-ui bug in that version...

Answer (score 0):

After some test on different version of jquery-ui I found the problem was on

```
, showAnim: "fold"
```

so I googled and found this ticket on internet, in the jquery-ui site: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9176

the ticket and the related tickets did not explained to me the real solution, but I can do without showAnim, I will reintroduce in my code when they will solve in some future release...

note that in current version (1.11.1) the problem is still present....